# Select and drag to get selected elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add a rectangle drag to my code here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cyTUX/39/ ,what this code does is onclick it changes states, it has 3 states, so if we select a state and drag it around the table cells, the cells involved in the drag gets that state.

so, what i want is, instead of selecting and dragging in that way, what i want to do is select a state and drag like a rectangle so all the table cells in the rectangle gets that state.

Any idea or example on how to do this?

Comment: you mean you want to like resize that rectangle and everything within area will change to that state?

Comment: something like a desktop drag, which looks like a rectangle, but the selected state should also be involved so the table cells get that value.

Comment: Something like this: http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drop/demo/selection ?

Comment: @Jeemusu , yes similar to this but first need to select the state and then drag.

Answer (score 3):

So I was writing an electron app and had the exact same problem.
Since I did not want to use jQuery I wrote something myself.
It took quite long to write it, so I made a plugin out of it that you can easily use yourself. It’s super small and does just that. I called it [DragSelect](https://thibaultjanbeyer.github.io/DragSelect/) and you can get it [from Github](https://github.com/ThibaultJanBeyer/DragSelect).

The cool thing about this is that you have **0 dependencies** and thus can use it with any framework you like.

The selection algorithm works like a charm and even gives you an independent multi-selection with modifier keys for free.

So taken from the [github readme](https://github.com/ThibaultJanBeyer/DragSelect):

## 1. Installation

### easy

Just download the file (minified) and add it to your document:

```
<script src="https://thibaultjanbeyer.github.io/DragSelect/ds.min.js"></script>
```

### npm

```
npm install --save-dev npm-dragselect
```

### bower

```
bower install --save-dev dragselect
```

That's it, you're ready to rock!
Of course, you can also just include the function within your code to save a request.

## Usage

Now in your JavaScript you can simply pass elements to the function like so:

### simple

Choose which elements can be selected:

```
var ds = new DragSelect({
  selectables: document.getElementsByClassName('selectable-nodes')
});
```

There is plenty more stuff you can do so make sure to read [the whole documentation on github](https://github.com/ThibaultJanBeyer/DragSelect)

## Enjoy

Answer (score 1):

create a new div

```
<div style="position:absolute;border:1px solid green;display:none" id="rectangle"></div>
```

and then something like this 
i hope you can work your way out and finish it its just and brute example how to approach this

```
var element = $("#rectangle");
// on mousedown
$(window).mousedown(function(e1){ 
   // first move element on mouse location
   element.show().css({top:e1.pageY, left:e1.pageX});
   // resize that div so it will be resizing while moouse is still pressed
   var resize = function(e2) {
       // you should check for direction in here and moves with top or left
      element.width(e2.pageX - e1.pageX);
      element.height(e2.pageY - e1.pageY);
   };
   $(window).mousemove(resize);
   // and finally unbind those functions when mouse click is released
   var unbind = function() {
       $(window).unbind(resize);
       $(window).unbind(unbind);
   };
   $(window).mouseup(unbind);
});
```

like this you can drag to create rectangle but only from left to right direction, you can see example in here
http://jsfiddle.net/dXduv/1
you can take actual positions from events to calculate which divs are inside and which are outside the area

Comment: i think this is a good start, i will work on this and get back to you if i have problems.

Comment: so i tried to achieve my drag with some other code i found online but it did not work out here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cyTUX/56/ ,this code allows to drag from any direction in the selected area, i was trying to select a state and do the rectangle drag but it did not happen, please help.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) has the ability to handle selection, drag and drop, resizing, and selection.  If you're already using jQuery, then adding jQuery UI is very easy.  You'll also find it includes many pre-made UI elements which makes form creation quick and easy.  Using a separate library like jQuery UI (also check out [Kendo UI](http://www.kendoui.com/)) is often a lot easier to do than trying to code complex Javascript features like this yourself.  You'll save time and likely have a more functional product.

[This example in particular](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#photo-manager) from jQuery UI may be of use to you.

Comment: this example looks like a select, drag and drop, what i want is a select and drag so that all the elements involved in the drag gets that value.

Comment: You can certainly achieve that using jQuery UI.  In this, you can also chain DOM elements so one element can have selection AND drag AND drop AND resize.  It shouldn't be just a little bit more code to achieve the effect you want, but this will at least get you there.